# Unicode symbol for BOLD arrow shows incorrect UI in UILabel iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

I am using unicode symbol for BOLD up & down arrow from this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Arrows

But its showing blue box around the arrow as shown in below screenshot

[image]

My code is as below

```
NSString *strMore = @"\u2B06" ;
NSString *strLess = @"\u2B07" ;

self.lblMore.text = strMore;
self.lblLess.text = strLess;
```

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong ?

Comment: Is is handled only by this text or are you using storyboards as well?

Comment: Its just a UILabel inside xib file. I am not using storyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arrow with the blue box around it, is the `Emoji` arrow with the same Unicode. Open Character Viewer on OS X (Control + Option + Space) to look up the codes and check the Unicode for the `Arrows` section from the left pane. Using that unicode should fix the issue as it won't mess with the Emoji arrow codes!

**Update** Sorry, I don't have access to a Mac at the moment, therefore I couldn't look up the code myself. Apparently if you add `\U0000FE0E` to your unicode, that'll avoid the Emoji. So in your case:

Instead of:

```
NSString *strMore = @"\u2B06" ; //This will map the character to the Emoji icon; the blue up arrow.
NSString *strLess = @"\u2B07" ; //This will map the character to the Emoji icon; the blue down arrow.
```

Write:

```
NSString *strMore = @"\u2B06\U0000FE0E" ; //This will disable Emoji character mapping and will display the proper unicode character, the black up arrow here.
NSString *strLess = @"\u2B07\U0000FE0E" ; //This will disable Emoji character mapping and will display the proper unicode character, the black down arrow here.
```

Let me know if that works!

**Second Update:**

Glad it worked! Didn't want to reference before making sure it works. Apparently this is mentioned in Apple's Developer forum for the paid developers. It's also mentioned in [this link](http://paulofierro.com/blog/2013/3/30/disabling-emoji-characters-with-unicode-variants) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208126/prevent-emoji-characters-from-showing).

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. But in Character Viewer as well its showing the same symbol that I am using currently.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on a shi**y Windows machine at the moment, that's why I couldn't check it myself. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Neeku for updated answer. This works perfectly :) Thanks a ton.
Just for curiosity , you told me `if you add \U0000FE0E to your unicode, that'll avoid the Emoji.` - where did you find this ? Can you please share the link as I need to learn :)

Comment: Sure! There you go with another update to the answer!

Comment: Thank you Neeku for reference links :)

Comment: Not sure why the wide-Unicode-escape `\U` is being used for all these examples, this Variation Selector is a BMP character that should be accessible simply as `\uFE0E`.

Comment: @bobince Hmm... I tried your suggestion, but [an error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0kBMj.png) occurs in that case.

Comment: OMG @bobince! Hadn't noticed that! Thanks. (: