# Disable unicode replacement emoji in Android Chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, unicode, emoji

Certain unicode characters in the Miscellaneous range would be nice to use, but most phones display them as emoji and that is unwanted because then they can't be styled by CSS font declarations. [I know there's a fix for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208126/prevent-emoji-characters-from-showing), but I have not found a solution for Android. Is it possible to disable them?

Example: http://jsbin.com/qopiyori/1/

Comment: The `U+FE0E` variation selector supported by iOS is the [official way](http://unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/StandardizedVariants.html) to select between emoji and text style. If Chrome on Android doesn't support this selector, I guess it's impossible to disable emojis.

Comment: a note to say this is still the case almost 2 years later...

Comment: https://crbug.com/491556

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, found the answer on another stack overflow question which worked for me:

add &#xFE0E; at the end of the string with the Unicode characters you do not want to be replaced with emoji icons.

[How to prevent Unicode characters from rendering as emoji in HTML from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip)

Comment: This doesn't work for the "Emoji for Google Chrome" extension

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. It's also hard to tell where to append the `&#xFE0E;` "at the end of the string". Is it `content: '\25B6 \FE0E&#xFE0E;'` or `content: '\25B6&#xFE0E;'` or `content: '\25B6 \FE0E'&#xFE0E;`, or ?

Comment: @SamSverko if you read the comments in referenced stack overflow you will notice that some of the comments indicate that it does not work for certain fonts. Sorry this did not work for you

Comment: @Rob I've tried it with different fonts. Is there a specific code-snippet that worked for you? Would be helpful to add that to your answer.

Comment: @SamSverko I no longer work at the place where I needed to do this. sorry. or I would pull it up and build you an example.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome, desktop version 75, seems to disambiguate its approach to rendering Unicode characters based on the first Unicode escape it encounters while loading a page. For instance, when parsed as the first HTML Unicode escape in a page source, and having no emoji equivalent, &#9207; seems to clarify to Chrome that the page contains escapes not to be rendered as emoji. I have not tried this in Android Chrome.

Comment: Not working with Samsung Internet 13.0.2.9 (Chromium version unknown, > 79).